# Creating a PDF output using Latex and R-Markdown... keep getting an error

Tags: pdftex, code, rstudio

I have a file I'm working on in R-Studio, and it was working really well (have about two pages worth of output that does work). But when I try to add to it with a new table, I keep getting:

```
> "Running pdflatex.exe on playerArbitrationProfile.tex...failed"
```

The problem is in the R-code that prints the table. Here's what I currently have for that:

```
<<echo=False,results=tex>>=   
print(xtable((transactions),align=c(rep('c',3),rep('c',ncol(transactions)-2))),sanitize.colnames.function=bold,include.rownames=FALSE,latex.environments = "left",hline=NULL,floating=FALSE, size="\\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\\selectfont",add.to.row=list(pos=list(1:(nrow(transactions)),0), command=c( '\\midrule\n','\\toprule\n')),tabular.environment = 'tabularx', width="7in")
@
```

The table (built in R) has three columns: transaction date (character), transaction team (character), and transaction description (character). The table has 17 observations. The transaction description column is slightly lengthy, but I don't think the length is the issue considering I tried running it without that column and it didn't make a difference (on another note, if anyone can give an easy way to get the text to wrap in that third column, that would be appreciated). Does anyone see any issues in the code above that would keep preventing my report from running?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  although i can't solve your problem (and even if i could, a compilable (non)working example would be very useful), i suggest that with this sort of problem, it's often a good idea to construct the code as an entirely separate job, and only incorporate it into the main job once it's working.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem whenever I've tried inserting a new table. Once I figure out the issue for this one, I'll be able to apply it to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be you are using `Sweave` (`results=tex`) syntax, but using `knitr` (where the syntax would be `results='asis'`)

In any case, the following compiles for me

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

<<data, echo=FALSE>>=
    transactions <- as.data.frame( list(
        date       = paste("date" , 1:17) ,
        team       = paste("team" , 1:17),
        decription = paste('description' , 1:17)
    ) )
@

<<setup, echo=FALSE>>=
    library(xtable)

    bold <- function(x) {
        paste0('\\textbf{' , x , '}')
    }
@

\begin{document}

<<table, echo=FALSE , results='asis'>>=   
    print(
        xtable(transactions,align=c(rep('c',3),rep('c',ncol(transactions)-2))) ,
        sanitize.colnames.function = bold,
        include.rownames=FALSE,
        latex.environments = "left",
        hline=NULL,
        floating=FALSE,
        size="\\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\\selectfont",
        add.to.row=list(pos=list(1:(nrow(transactions)),0), command=c( '\\midrule\n','\\toprule\n')),
        tabular.environment = 'tabularx',
        width="7in"
    )
@

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Working Sweave version:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

<<data, echo=FALSE>>=
    transactions <- as.data.frame( list(
        date       = paste("date" , 1:17) ,
        team       = paste("team" , 1:17),
        decription = paste('description' , 1:17)
    ) )
@

<<setup, echo=FALSE>>=
    library(xtable)

    bold <- function(x) {
        paste0('\\textbf{' , x , '}')
    }
@

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<table, echo=FALSE , results=tex>>=   
    print(
        xtable(transactions,align=c(rep('c',3),rep('c',ncol(transactions)-2))) ,
        sanitize.colnames.function = bold,
        include.rownames=FALSE,
        latex.environments = "left",
        hline=NULL,
        floating=FALSE,
        size="\\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\\selectfont",
        add.to.row=list(pos=list(1:(nrow(transactions)),0), command=c( '\\midrule\n','\\toprule\n')),
        tabular.environment = 'tabularx',
        width="7in"
    )
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm actually using Sweave, not knitr. Is there a different syntax I should be using? I've already printed multiple tables successfully using that syntax, but this one just isn't working.